# Spring Configuration issue with JPA ConfigClass

Tags: spring, app-config

I originally was using entirely xml-less JavaConfig configuration for my application and found out the app server I have to deploy for production doesn't support this.  So I've been going back and trying to change as little as possible to get my app running again.  I'm still planning to use `@Configuration` classes, but configuring them to load up via `web.xml` instead of in `WebAppInitializer`.

I'm thought that specifying

```
contextClass = org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
```

and

```
contextConfigLocation = {ConfigClasses}
```

in the `web.xml` would accomplish this.  But now when my web-app starts up, it's throwing a fit that it can't start the Persistance Layer:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Here is my code:

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <!-- Map all errors to Spring MVC handler method. See CustomErrorController.generalError() -->  
   <display-name>app</display-name>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.ApplicationConfig 
                    org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.DataSourceConfig
                    org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.DefaultDataSourceConfig
                    org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.JpaConfig
                    org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.SecurityConfig
                    org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.MailConfig
       </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
         </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.ApplicationConfig 
                           org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.DataSourceConfig
                           org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.DefaultDataSourceConfig
                           org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.DefaultDataSourceConfig.JpaConfig
                           org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.SecurityConfig
                           org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.MailConfig  
               </param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**ApplicationConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, excludeFilters = @Filter({Controller.class, Configuration.class}))
class ApplicationConfig {   
    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }   

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

**JpaConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaConfig.class);

    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;
    @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
    private String showSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.provider_class}")
    private String connectionProviderClass;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}")
    private String maxSize;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}")
    private String minSize;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}")
    private String acquireIncrement;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}")
    private String idleTestPeriod;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}")
    private String maxStatements;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}")
    private String timeout;

    @Bean
    public DataSource efiDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }       

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(efiDataSource());        
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.appname");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES, "/data/type_request.sql");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, Integer.valueOf(maxSize));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_MIN_SIZE, Integer.valueOf(minSize));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, Integer.valueOf(acquireIncrement));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_IDLE_TEST_PERIOD, Integer.valueOf(idleTestPeriod));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_TIMEOUT, Integer.valueOf(timeout));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, Integer.valueOf(maxStatements));
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);                
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();        
        return manager;
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure where the wires are getting crossed.  My gut feeling is that either it's not loading the JpaConfig at all or it's for some reason trying to generate the Repository/Dao classes first and not loading the Persistance.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Below is a more complete stack trace:

```
2014-02-14 15:58:49.587 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.w.servlet.DispatcherServlet - 

Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configureEntityManagerFactory' defined in class org.deloitte.cms.eua.config.JpaConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:110) ~[hibernate-ehcache-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:529) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:374) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:259) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:83) ~[hibernate-ehcache-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Not 100% sure why changing to web.xml startup instead of web.xml would cause this, but the problem was that the Cache was being initialized multiple times.  I changed JpaConfig to use SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory instead of EhCacheRegionFactory